# How to use double For loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to define file path and file name using For loop.

After doing the main action (that is count of rows in this example), i need to path to the next file path and the next file name at the same time and then to do the main action (rows count).

But i have some problems using Next, because order that i am trying to use is wrong. Maybe someone can help with this? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub CountRows()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim lngNextRow As Long, lngRowCount As Long
    Dim LastRow
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    LastRow = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lngNextRow = wsDest.Range("F" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Here I define a Path to the file
    For Each cl In wsDest.Range("G11:G" & LastRow)
        strFolder = cl.Value

        'Here I define File name
        For Each cell In wsDest.Range("C11:C" & LastRow)
            strFile = cell.Value

            'Here happens count of row or any other action
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
            lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount - 1
            wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
            lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1

        'Then i need to pass to the next Path & The next file name
        Next cell
    Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Indent your code and you will see your mistake.

Comment: you need (at least) next to be correctly : for a (for b next b) next a. Invert next cl / next cell is a minimum to make things work.

Comment: @mansuetus thanx, about order of next cl and next cell, i edited it.

Comment: It's still not working? I'm not sure you want to use a double-loop. Right now, you're opening each file in `ColumnC` with the first path in `ColumnG`, then each file in `ColumnC` with the second path in `ColumnG`, and so on so forth. It feels like you're trying to open file on first line with path on first line, then file on second line with path on second line, and so on so forth. If so, you need to remove one layer of `for`.

Comment: @BernardSaucier yes, i need to open first file in column C from the first path from column G, then second file from column C and second path from column G and so on. Doing for each file count of rows. So to do this do i need to delete one For loop?

Comment: If it's *open C, then open G*, use one loop. If it's *open all G for each C*, then use two loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 2-loop structure with this :

```
For Each cl In wsDest.Range("G11:G" & LastRow)

    strFolder = cl.Value
    strFile = wsDest.Range("G" & cl.Row).Value

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
    lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount - 1
    wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
    lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1

Next cl
```

It will open the file on each line with the folder on the same line

Comment: It's been a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

In the result I used this in order to list files by rows:

```
For Each cl In wsDest.Range("G11:G" & LastRow)
strFolder = cl.Value
iCol = 3
strFile = Cells(lngNextRow, iCol).Value


Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount - 1
wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1
Next
```